# Array To Array MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, system, mips

I'm trying to copy the even contents of one array to the other array. My code runs with no problem but the values being printed from the array are 000000 not the values of the array.

My goal is to copy the even numbers of array0 to array1 and print them to the screen.

My Code:

```
.data
array0: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
length: .word 10
array1: .space 20
nl: .asciiz ""
label: .asciiz "Values: "

.text
.globl main
main:

lw $t2, length
move $t0, $zero
move $t1, $zero
move $t2, $zero
move $t3, $zero

la $a0, label
li $v0, 4
syscall

start:
lw $t5, array0($t0)
andi $t4, $t5, 1
beq $t4, 0, even
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi, $t0, $t0, 4
blt $t1, $t2, start
j end

even:
sw $t5, array1($t3)
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $t0, $t0, 4
addi $t3, $t3, 4
blt $t1, $t2, start

end:
lw $a0, array1($t6)
li $v0, 1
syscall

la $a0, nl
la $v0, 4
syscall

addi $t6, $t6, 4
bne $t6, 20, end
li $v0, 10
syscall

.end main
```

Comment: You loaded `length` to `$t2` and then overwrited `$t2` by `$zero`. Are you sure it is what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of `$t2` to zero after loading `length` to `$t2`. The first element of the array is evaluated, but it is not even. Then, `1 < 0` is false and the jump $blt $t1, $t2, start`is not taken. After that, the jump`j end`is taken and the contents of`array1` is printed.

Just remove the deletion of length information

```
move $t2, $zero
```

and the even contents will be printed.